# Permission required for migrating sites from SP2013 to o365 - Metalogix

Tags: migration, sharepoint-permissions, metalogix

We are going to migrate sharepoint 2013 site to o365 using metalogix tool. So, **Which permission should I need on source SP2013 server & on o365 to use metalogix?** Only site collection admin rights are sufficient or do I need any permissions on DB & farm for SP 2013? Also should I need any permissions in o365 admin portal?

Please suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I havent read ShareGate specification so you can try User Policy, but for migration we recommend to have full access to both SharePoint Environments:

- **SharePoint Server** - theoreticaly you just need set only **User Policy - Full Control** for migration account on all web applications (can be set in Central Administration > Web Applications), but probably ShareGate can try access some system information, in this case you should be **SharePoint Administrator account or be part of SharePoint Administrato Group**
- **SharePoint Online - SharePoint Online Administrator role** - cause you probably need to create structure as sites.